# Android Camera preview has 'laces' or 'Mosaic' on the border use SurfaceTexture,Why the picture cannot full fill up the screen?

Tags: android, camera

I want to make camera preview only, but some reason causes the problem like the picture shows below:

[image: problem picture]

I use a subclass of `GLSurfaceView` to preview. From the picture we can see the picture can't fully fill up the screen, but if I preview use `mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);` then the result is correct.

Is `SurfaceTexture` display different on different device? Is `SurfaceTexture` or `GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` memory alignment?
Should `SurfaceTexture` make some configuration to fully fill up the screen?

Thanks.

The code I use almost like this:

activity content layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.camera.PreviewSurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

PreviewSurfaceView.java:

```
public class PreviewSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    private PreviewRenderer mRender;
    public PreviewSurfaceView(Context context) {
        this(context,null);
    }
    public PreviewSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        mRender = new PreviewRenderer(context,this);

        setRenderer(mRender);

        setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }
}
```

PreviewRenderer.java:

```
public class PreviewRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        initShaders();
        mCamera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

        mTextureId = mGlesHelper.createTextureOESID();

        mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(mTextureId);

        mSurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(new SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFrameAvailable: tid = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            }
        });
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mSurfaceTexture);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        mSurfaceWidth = width;
        mSurfaceHeight = height;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        if (mSurfaceTexture != null){
            mSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
        }
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.6f, 0.5f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        GLES20.glViewport(0,0,mSurfaceWidth,mSurfaceHeight);
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mRenderProgram);

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mVertexCoorLocation,3,GLES20.GL_FLOAT,false,0,mScreenVertexBuffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mVertexCoorLocation);

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoorLocation,2,GLES20.GL_FLOAT,false,0,mTextureBuffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoorLocation);

        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureId);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mOesTextureLocation, 0);

        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,mIndics.length,GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,mIndicsBuffer);

        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mVertexCoorLocation);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoorLocation);

        mSurfaceView.requestRender();
    }
}
```

vertex.glsl:

```
attribute vec4 a_vertexCoor;
attribute vec2 a_textureCoor;

varying vec2 v_textureCoor;

void main() {
    v_textureCoor = vec2(1.0 - a_textureCoor.y,1.0 - a_textureCoor.x);
    gl_Position = a_vertexCoor;
}
```

fragement.glsl:

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require

precision highp float;

uniform samplerExternalOES u_OEStexture;

varying vec2 v_textureCoor;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_OEStexture,v_textureCoor);
}
```

additional：

[image: about phone]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through a day's study,I find the reason finally.The step of change as follow:

1.Change vertex.glsl and add some sentences:

```
uniform mat4 uVertexMatrix;
uniform mat4 uTextureMatrix;

void main() {
    gl_Position = uVertexMatrix*a_vertexCoor;
    vec2 textureCoor = (uTextureMatrix*vec4(a_textureCoor,0,1)).xy;

    v_textureCoor = vec2(textureCoor.x,textureCoor.y);
}
```

2.Change onDrawFrame() method and add some sentences:

```
....
//important code
mSurfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(mTextureMatrix);
...
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mVertexMatrixLocation,1,false,mVertexMatrix,0);
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mTextureMatrixLocation,1,false, mTextureMatrix,0);
...
```

Then you can get the correct result through two steps descript above.

In the previous `vertex.glsl`,the code `v_textureCoor = vec2(1.0 - textureCoor.x,1.0-textureCoor.y);` can transform the texture to get correct view based on https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures ,but it not works always on various devices.

In many open source projects,such as [google/grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) and [aiyaapp/AAVT](https://github.com/aiyaapp/AAVT),matrix-transform has been used to handle texture.They inspire me,and handle the problem finally.